# How to use a nested typedef in a template?

Tags: c++, templates

I want to derive a type `Test` from a templated type `Base` which I specialise on the derived type (i.e. `Base<Test>`).

Inside the templated type, I want to make use of a typedef defined in the derived type (the template parameter).

However, I get this compile error:

```
error C2039: 'X' : is not a member of 'Test'
```

Here is the code snippet:

```
template <typename T>
class Base
{
protected:
  void func(typename T::X x) {}
};


class Test : public Base<Test>
{
public:
  typedef int X;
};
```

Is this doable, and if so, what is the fix I need to make?

(I see a couple of answers for this kind of problem but it looks like my scenario isn't fixed by prefixing typename - is it something to do with deriving from a template specialised with the derived type?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
template <typename T> struct Traits;

template <typename Derived>
class Base
{
   protected:
      void func(typename Traits<Derived>::X x) {}
};


class Test;

template <> struct Traits<Test>
{
  typedef int X;
};


class Test : public Base<Test>
{
};
```

Comment: I think that's how you're supposed to do this kind of thing - I suppose it's a bit like extracting an interface to avoid circular reference between two types.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively to the typedef, you can also declare the type as second template argument in the base class:

```
template <typename T, typename X>
class Base
{
protected:
  void func(X x) {}
};


class Test : public Base<Test, int>
{
public:
//  typedef int X;
};
```

Comment: I like that. Plus one, and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Although it's not the purest CRTP.

Answer (score 2):

You have a circularity which cannot be resolved with forward declarations. But this will work, although (I suspect) not quite so strongly defined as you wanted.

```
template <typename T>
class Base
{
protected:
    template<typename Y>
    void func(Y x) {}
};

class Test : public Base<Test>
{
public:
    typedef int X;
};
```

If `func` were public, then you could then write

```
Test t;
Test::X x;
t.func(x)
```

which is satisfactory for any use of the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern I think of.

Comment: This works for my sample demo code above, but I don't think it'd work for the more complex actual code I'm trying to compile :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about this behavior, maybe someone can clarify it. But as I understand by the moment you do `: public Base<Test>` the type name X doesn't exists (since is declared below).

If you create a wrapper class before making the inheritance the type would exists by the moment you do the inheritance and the template instantiation will work.

This compiles with VC++ 2013

```
template <typename T>
class Base
{
protected:
    void func(typename T::X x) {}
};


class TestWrapper
{
public:
    typedef int X; //Declared, now it exists for the compiler
};

class Test
    :public Base<TestWrapper> //Compiles correctly
{

};
```